# Jenkins MSBUILD plugin raises "Could not locate the assembly CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine..."

Tags: jenkins, msbuild, crystal-reports

This problem is happening on a Jenkins v2.249.3 build server running on Windows Server 2012 and the MBUILD plugin is installed used to build a VS.NET 2013 solution. This solution has references to Crystal Reports Runtime libraries in order to render the Crystal Reports viewer.

The problem occurs when Jenkins kicks off the MSBUILD step it cannot find `CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine`, `CrystalDecisions.Shared` and `CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms` on the machine.

I've installed the Crystal Reports runtime `CRRuntime_32bit_13_0_18.msi` from the Crystal site but I'm getting errors in the Jenkins console such as:

`Primary reference "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1605,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors. [C:\Users\Jenkins\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\myaspnetapp\crystalLibrary\CrystalLibrary.csproj]`

As well as:

`For SearchPath "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}". Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\Facades\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. For SearchPath "{Registry:Software\Microsoft\.NETFramework,v4.5.2,AssemblyFoldersEx}". Considered AssemblyFoldersEx locations. For SearchPath "{AssemblyFolders}". Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\SDK\Assemblies\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\120\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\120\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\120\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.0\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\140\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\140\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\ADOMD.NET\140\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist. For SearchPath "{GAC}". Considered "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL", which was not found in the GAC. For SearchPath "{RawFileName}". Considered treating "CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304, processorArchitecture=MSIL" as a file name, but it didn't exist. For SearchPath "bin\Debug\". Considered "bin\Debug\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.winmd", but it didn't exist. Considered "bin\Debug\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll", but it didn't exist. Considered "bin\Debug\CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.exe", but it didn't exist.`

Answer (score 0):

It appears the **type** of crystal runtime you install matters here:

The runtime that **worked** for me was  `CRforVS_redist_install_64bit_nn_n_nn.zip` (note the **CRforVS_redist** in the name). This is the Crystal for Visual Studio redistribution runtime for  development machines. Jenkins is a build machine so it also needs to have the  Visual Studio version that a human developer's machine would have.

My mistake was installing the runtime named `CRRuntime_32bit_nn_n_nn.msi`. This type of runtime is installed on server where the built application is deployed.